# ClearInterval() does not work on existing interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I have written the following function for a school project, but the `clearinterval()` is not working. I have looked at several questions about the same problem and it was a problem with the scope most of the time.
However, I think my function uses a global variable, which should work. It doesn't, and I have no idea why. Please enlighten me.

HTML (actually part of a table with similiar rows)

```
<tr id="row35" data-uitval="1" class="">
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="knopje" class="tabeluur" data-uur="35" onclick="check(this)">
            <p>✕</p>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td> other cells... </td>
</tr>
```

Code (Javascript, in `<head>`-tag)

```
var fadingFunc;
var busy = false;

function check(uurID) {
    if(busy) {
        $('#foutmelding').html('Uw vorige bewerking loopt nog. Wacht totdat deze is afgelopen.')
    } else {
        uitval(uurID);
    };
};

function uitval(uurID) {

    // makes the button child (<p>) fade out and back in continuously
    fadingFunc = window.setInterval(fadeBlink(uurID), 2000);

    $.post(
        'AnswerMe.php', 
        {
        // send stuff
        }, 
        function(data) {
            if(data === 'succes: uitval toegevoegd') {
                window.clearInterval(fadingFunc);
                // do stuff
            } else if(data === 'succes: uitval verwijderd') {
                window.clearInterval(fadingFunc);
                // do stuff
            } else {
                window.clearInterval(fadingFunc);
                // do stuff
            };
        }
    );
};
```

Note 1: I stripped all the code that actually does something, since it is irrelevant for this question.
Note 2: I tested this on my computer (localhost, google chrome) and `fadingFunc` does hold a value in global scope (tested via console in developers mode)

Comment: `window.setInterval(fadeBlink(uurID), 2000)` – you are _calling_ the function here, instead of passing the function _reference_ to setInterval. You need to wrap the function call into an anonymous function, if you want to pass a parameter to it.

Comment: @CBroe I changed it to `fadingFunc = window.setInterval(function(uurID) {fadeBlink(uurID)}, 2000);`, but now it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: Without parameter for the anonymous function, `window.setInterval(function() {fadeBlink(uurID)}, 2000)`

Comment: Unless `fadeBlink(uurID)` returns a function (which I doubt), you're calling `setInterval` like so: `setInterval(undefined, 2000)`.  So, clearing the interval won't actually do anything.

Comment: @canon I think not, it looped before I changed it (so when it still was `window.setInterval(fadeBlink(uurID), 2000)`). Now it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

So if I got it - you want the X inside the button to blink while the post request is waiting for the response.

Your code is almost there but you are not using the `setInterval` correctly and you are choosing a poor approach to achieve that. First we will fix your code and then check out my approach using a CSS animation.

To fix your code:

1. Code must be placed inside the `<head>` tag since you are using some inline call.
2. Remove all `window.` not needed - use `setInterval(` instead of `window.setInterval`.
3. When setting the actuall interval function wrap the target function with a function -`setInterval(function(){ fadeBlink(uurID); }, 2000)`

See It work: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/atsyd19t/)

The second approach which I think will be better for you is to add a class before the request and remove it when its done. the class obviuslly will be animated.

Second approach: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/n8dz85dw/)

Second appraoch code:

**JS**

```
var busy = false;
function check(uurID) {
    if(busy) $('#foutmelding').html('Uw vorige bewerking loopt nog.');
    else uitval(uurID);
}
function uitval(uurID) {
    $(uurID).addClass('blink');
    busy = true;
    $.post('http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/', 
           { test:'test' }, 
           function() {
              $(uurID).removeClass('blink');
              busy = false;
           }
    );
}
```

**CSS**

```
.blink p {
-webkit-animation-name: blinker;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-name: blinker;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-name: blinker;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
0% { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.0; }
100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
0% { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.0; }
100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
0% { opacity: 1.0; }
50% { opacity: 0.0; }
100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```